# YEAR(AVG(UNIX(date))) different from ROUND(AVG(YEAR(date)))

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, unix-timestamp

Summarizing a practice question:
I need to query the average year from a `datetime` column. My initial solution was to `YEAR(AVG())` all dates. But since I can't `AVG()` a `datetime`, I convert the dates to unix, then back to datetime:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date1))))
FROM table1;
```

Which returns `1980`

The correct query is:

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(AVG(YEAR(date1)))
FROM table1;
```

Which returns `1960`
The second query is better for clear reasons, but why are the results different?

Comment: You definitely have dates before `'1970-01-01 00:00:00'`, because your correct average value is 1960. Unix Timestamp values are undefined for dates before this time.

Comment: "If you pass an out-of-range date to UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), it returns 0. The valid range of values is the same as for the TIMESTAMP data type: '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999' UTC. " Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Comment: Even if there are no date before 1970, your first query is computing average on seconds (a different unit of time); while the second query is computing the average on years (another unit of time). You cannot expect them to give same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your data contains dates earlier than `1970-01-01`. The [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function returns 0 for dates earlier than the epoch:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1969-12-31')
-- 0
```

Hence the result for first query is biased as it does not count < 1970 dates properly.